# How to return the value of CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations in function?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, gps, core-location

The problem iam having is that when i call the getCityName() function in other classes it returns nil because didUpdateLocations needs more time to run, how to solve this Async problem? and How to return the value of CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations in function?

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class userCurrentLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
    var cityName:String!

     init(cityName:String) {
        super.init()
        setUp()
    }

    func getCityName() -> String?{
        return cityName
    }

    func setUp() {
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locations.last!.geocode { placemark, error in
            if let error = error as? CLError {
                print("CLError:", error)
                return
            } else if let placemark = placemark?.first {
                    self.cityName = placemark.locality ?? ""
                    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}

extension CLLocation {
    func geocode(completion: @escaping (_ placemark: [CLPlacemark]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)  {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self, completionHandler: completion)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class userCurrentLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
    var cityName:String!


    //1. Add a closure callback
    var didGetCity: ((String) -> Void)?


    //2. Send City Name when received
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locations.last!.geocode { placemark, error in
            if let error = error as? CLError {
                print("CLError:", error)
                return
            } else if let placemark = placemark?.first {
                    self.cityName = placemark.locality ?? ""

                    // Check for null 
                    // Send city name in the completion block
                    if (self.didGetCity != nil){
                    self.didGetCity?(self.cityName)
                    }
                    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }
    }


    //3. Add code to your class where you need the city Name

    var City : String?


    let locationManager = userCurrentLocation (cityName: "")
        locationManager.didGetCity = {
            [weak self] city in
            self!.City = city
        }
```

Comment: There isn't much point in using `[weak self]` if you are just going to force unwrap it. I suggest that you either retain a strong `self` or use a conditional unwrap.

Comment: @Paulw11 You are right. It was an error from my end

Comment: Also, the `City` property should be `city`

Answer (score -1):

You can use Delegate to tell the main class that everything is ready and use that value

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


protocol userCurrentLocationDelegate: class {
  func userCurrentLocationDidGetLocation(_ userLocation: userCurrentLocation)
}

class userCurrentLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
    var cityName:String!
    weak var delegate: userCurrentLocationDelegate?

 init(cityName:String) {
    super.init()
    setUp()
}

func getCityName() -> String?{
    return cityName
}

func setUp() {
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    locations.last!.geocode { placemark, error in
        if let error = error as? CLError {
            print("CLError:", error)
            return
        } else if let placemark = placemark?.first {
                self.cityName = placemark.locality ?? ""
                manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                delegate?.userCurrentLocationDidGetLocation(self)
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
```

}

```
extension CLLocation {
    func geocode(completion: @escaping (_ placemark: [CLPlacemark]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)  {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self, completionHandler: completion)
    }
}
```

and in Main class that calls this one use delegate from this callback to start calling the city name